# GoViral Social Media AIR extension - Facebook integration

Tags: android, ios, facebook, actionscript-3, air

I'm having problems with the GoViral ANE for iOS/Android - http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/

Whenever I attempt to build the app, either as a debug or full package build, the build fails. I get no error message at all, and attempting to manually install the .apk on an android device gets the message 'App installation failed' with no more detail than that.

I've managed to get the app building again by removing the code below from the appname-app.xml file, which I copied from the GoViral plugins getting started pdf. After removing this I can build the app, and install it to my device, but can't use the Facebook part of the GoViral plugin.

```
              <application>
                    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
                    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="Login"/>
                    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProviderXXXXXXXX"
                    android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider" />
                    <meta-data android:name="air.com.blugames.popartify.ApplicationId" android:value="XXXXXXXX"/>
                </application>
```

I replaced the XXXXXXXX with my Facebook ID in the app, but I have hidden it here

I can't see anything wrong with this code, but I am not too familiar with the XML side of AIR development.

Has anyone had this problem before/can you see anything glaringly obvious?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest ANE? v4.6.0 and the latest AIR SDK 17.0.0.124?

Here is a copy of my manifest. Note that it doesn't include this first line but it does work.

```
<meta-data android:name="air.com.yourcompany.example.ApplicationId" android:value="000000000000000"/>
```

....

```
<android>
<manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
<manifest android:installLocation="auto" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="Login"/>
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider2154XXXXXXXXXXX”
android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider" />
</application>
</manifest>
]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```